# How to implement IntoIterator for an enum of iterable variants?

Tags: rust, enums, iterator

I have an enum that has different variant possibilities like so:

```rust
pub enum Enum {
  Empty,
  Single(Struct),
  Multi(Vec<Struct>),
}
```

And I want to create the typical three iteration functions to get `Struct`s for `Enum`: one `.iter()` for an iterator of references, and two flavors of `.into_iter()` to get iterators over references and over values.  How does one do this?

Here is my failed attempt:

```
use std::{iter, slice, vec};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Struct(u32);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Enum {
  Empty,
  Single(Struct),
  Multi(Vec<Struct>),
}

impl Enum {
  fn iter(&self) -> slice::Iter<'_, Struct> {
    match self {
      Enum::Empty => iter::empty(),
      Enum::Single(s) => iter::once(s),
      Enum::Multi(v) => v.iter(),
    }
  }
}

impl IntoIterator for Enum {
  type Item = Struct;
  type IntoIter = vec::IntoIter<Struct>;

  fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
    match self {
      Enum::Empty => iter::empty(),
      Enum::Single(s) => iter::once(s),
      Enum::Multi(v) => v.into_iter(),
    }
  }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Enum {
  type Item = &'a Struct;
  type IntoIter = slice::Iter<'a, Struct>;

  fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
    self.iter()
  }
}

fn main() {
  let enums = vec![
    Enum::Empty,
    Enum::Single(Struct(1)),
    Enum::Multi(vec![Struct(2), Struct(3)])];
  for e in enums {
    for s in e.iter() {
      println!(".iter() over refs: {:?}", s);
    }
    for s in &e {  // leverages IntoIterator for &'a Enum
      println!(".into_iter() over refs: {:?}", s);
    }
    for s in e {  // leverages IntoIterator for Enum
      println!(".into_iter() moves: {:?}", s);
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8f1755e53f7d0f33b8fa4ee63e121df5)</sup>

I'm failing to see how to coerce the `iter::empty` and `iter::once` into the `slice::Iter` and `vec::IntoIter`, or is that even the right thing to want to do?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have this enum? Why not just use a plain `Vec`?

Comment: I've simplified my actual use-case here.  In reality these represent different operations.  One operation (think NOT) takes just one input, but another operation (think OR) takes multiple, and another is a dummy operation that takes none.  So really `Enum { Terminal, Not(Struct), Or(Vec<Struct>) }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, all these variants can be represented by slices or easily converted into `Vec`s. So you can do that and then use their iterators directly.

```
impl IntoIterator for Enum {
    type Item = Struct;
    type IntoIter = vec::IntoIter<Struct>;
  
    fn into_iter(self) -> vec::IntoIter<Struct> {
        let vec = match self {
            Enum::Empty => Vec::new(),
            Enum::Single(single) => vec![single],
            Enum::Multi(vec) => vec,
        };
        
        vec.into_iter()
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Enum {
  type Item = &'a Struct;
  type IntoIter = slice::Iter<'a, Struct>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> slice::Iter<'a, Struct> {
        let slice = match self {
            Enum::Empty => &[],
            Enum::Single(single) => std::slice::from_ref(single),
            Enum::Multi(vec) => vec.as_slice(),
        };
        
        slice.iter()
    }
}
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c72347690295c35bfe2d1c849f607f19).

---

If you actually have different enough variants that you can't coerce them into an existing iterator, you can implement the iterator as an enum of other iterators. Here's what that would look like:

```
pub enum EnumIntoIter {
    Empty(std::iter::Empty<Struct>),
    Single(std::iter::Once<Struct>),
    Multi(std::vec::IntoIter<Struct>),
}

impl Iterator for EnumIntoIter {
    type Item = Struct;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Struct> {
        match self {
            EnumIntoIter::Empty(iter) => iter.next(),
            EnumIntoIter::Single(iter) => iter.next(),
            EnumIntoIter::Multi(iter) => iter.next(),
        }
    }
}

impl IntoIterator for Enum {
    type Item = Struct;
    type IntoIter = EnumIntoIter;
  
    fn into_iter(self) -> EnumIntoIter {
        match self {
            Enum::Empty => EnumIntoIter::Empty(std::iter::empty()),
            Enum::Single(single) => EnumIntoIter::Single(std::iter::once(single)),
            Enum::Multi(vec) => EnumIntoIter::Multi(vec.into_iter()),
        }
    }
}

pub enum EnumIter<'a> {
    Empty(std::iter::Empty<&'a Struct>),
    Single(std::iter::Once<&'a Struct>),
    Multi(std::slice::Iter<'a, Struct>),
}

impl<'a> Iterator for EnumIter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a Struct;
    
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a Struct> {
        match self {
            EnumIter::Empty(iter) => iter.next(),
            EnumIter::Single(iter) => iter.next(),
            EnumIter::Multi(iter) => iter.next(),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a Enum {
    type Item = &'a Struct;
    type IntoIter = EnumIter<'a>;
  
    fn into_iter(self) -> EnumIter<'a> {
        match self {
            Enum::Empty => EnumIter::Empty(std::iter::empty()),
            Enum::Single(single) => EnumIter::Single(std::iter::once(single)),
            Enum::Multi(vec) => EnumIter::Multi(vec.iter()),
        }
    }
}
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5de111eddba2571be9af2d98fbf46ce2)

Comment: Is that the most performant way of doing it?  It felt weird to have to create an empty Vec just to get a compatible iterator -- but maybe that's just as performant as any other way?

Comment: Creating a Vec for the `Empty` case is not an issue, the `Single` case is the worst of them since it actually has to allocate in order to hold the single element. I've added an example implementation closer to your original code. I can't say for certain which is better, though converting to vecs is more concise.